# How to order table with title including numbers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Titles in my table looks like that:

```
"Title 100"
"Title 17"
"Title 2"
"Title 23"
```

And I want to order them like below:

```
"Title 2"
"Title 17"
"Title 23"
"Title 100"
```

When I use `Post.order("title ASC").each { |post|  puts post.title }` I got below results:

```
"Title 100"
"Title 17"
"Title 2"
"Title 23"
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you try `Post.order("cast(replace(title,'Title ','') as int)")` ?

Comment: Do all titles actually start with `Title `?

Answer (score 0):

You can sort by custom method defined in your model.

`Post.all.sort_by(&:custom_post_sort)`

**Post model**

```
def custom_post_sort
  title.scan(/\d/).join('').to_i
end
```

Answer (score 0):

It will return array of `titles` in asc order.

```
 Post.pluck(:title).sort_by { |x| x[/\d+/].to_i }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if title of the post always starts with "**Title**",

```
Post.order("CONVERT(SUBSTR(title,3),SIGNED INTEGER)")
```

Answer (score 0):

### Ascending Order:

```
> Post.pluck(:title).sort_by{|e| e[/\d+/].to_i}
#=> ["Title 2", "Title 17", "Title 23", "Title 100"]
```

### Descending Order:

```
 > Post.pluck(:title).sort_by{|e| -e[/\d+/].to_i}
 #=> ["Title 100", "Title 23", "Title 17", "Title 2"]
```